# How does this memory allocator work?

Tags: c

So, I just sat down and decided to write a memory allocator. I was tired, so I just threw something together. What I ended up with was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

char buffer[BUFSIZE];
char *next = buffer;

void *alloc(int n){
    if(next + n <= buffer + BUFSIZE){
        next += n;
        return (void *)(next - n);
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

void afree(void *c){
    next = (char *)c;
}

int main(){
    int *num = alloc(sizeof(int));
    *num = 5643;
    printf("%d: %d", *num, sizeof(int));
    afree(num);
}
```

For some reason, this works. But I can not explain why it works. It may have to do with the fact that I am tired, but I really can not see why it works. So, this is what it should be doing, logically, and as I understand it:

1. It creates a char array with a pointer which points to the first element of the array.
2. When I call alloc with a value of 4 (which is the size of an int, as I have tested down below), it should set next to point to the fourth element of the array. It should then return a char pointer to the first 4 bytes of the array casted to a void pointer.
3. I then set that value to something greater than the max value of a char. C should realise that that isn't possible and should then truncate it to *num % sizeof(char).

I have one guess as to why this works: When the char pointer is casted to a void pointer and then gets turned into an integer it somehow changes the size of the pointer so that it is able to point to an integer. (I haven't only tried this memory allocator with integers, but with structures as well, and it seems to work with them as well).

Is this guess correct, or am I too tired to think?

EDIT:
[image: This is what it looks like in my mind]

EDIT 2: I think I've understood it. I realised that my phrasing from yesterday was quite bad. The thing which threw me off was the fact that the returned pointer actually points to a char, but I am still somehow able to store an integer value.

Comment: Get some sleep, and then look at it again.  My guess is you will understand it then.

Comment: I think you are getting what is pointed to and what points missed up.  A `void *` can be much larger than the max size of a character.  Is this what is confusing you?

Comment: "It should then return a char pointer to the first 4 bytes of the array casted to a void pointer." Why? It returns a `void *` which gets cast to an `int *`.

Comment: Generally speaking, it doesn\`t _always_ work. Allocate two floats, set them to 1.0, then free the first float allocated. Next, allocate a double and also set it to 1.0 and then check the second float value. It changed.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: Good observation. In fact, it's completely broken for any sequence of `alloc()/afree()` that is not pairwise matched in a LIFO order. Charitably, it's a stack.

Comment: @RadLexus Well, next is a pointer to a char. I then set next to point to the fourth element of the array. I then return next - n (the first element) which should be a char, but before I return it I cast it to a void pointer.

Comment: @Hogan I think so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, indeed I should, it's been an exhausting day.

Comment: Well, it "works" because you're only calling it exactly *once*, and because you're probably being your own judge of what constitutes "working". If you were trying to use this for real, you would probably hit alignment issues sooner or later.

Comment: Your picture is correct -- remember a `void *` can point to anything -- so you say char in your picture, but it could be byte or word etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The allocator posted implements a mark and release allocation scheme:

- `alloc(size)` returns a valid pointer if there is at least `size` unallocated bytes available in the arena.  The available size is reduced accordingly.  Note that this pointer can only be used to store bytes, as it is not properly aligned for anything else.  Furthermore, from a strict interpretation of the C Standard, even if the pointer is properly aligned, using it as a pointer to any other type would violate the strict aliasing rule.
- `afree(ptr)` resets the arena to the state is was before `alloc()` returned `ptr`.  It would be a useful extension to make `afree(NULL)` reset the arena to its initial state.

Note that the `main()` function attempts to use the pointer returned by `alloc(sizeof(int))` as a pointer to `int`.  This invokes undefined behavior because there is no guarantee that `buffer` is properly aligned for this, and because of the violation of the strict aliasing rule.

Note also that the printf format `printf("%d: %d", *num, sizeof(int));` is incorrect for the second argument.  It should be `printf("%d: %zd", *num, sizeof(int));` or `printf("%d: %d", *num, (int)sizeof(int));` if the C runtime library is too old to support `%zd`.

Comment: Yes, some sleep was all I needed, I now get it!

Answer (score 0):

Actually! I came up with a reason for the behaviour! This is what I was wondering, however, I wasn't too good at putting my thoughs into words yesterday (sorry). I modified my code to something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

char buffer[BUFSIZE];
char *next = buffer;

void *alloc(int n){
    if(next + n <= buffer + BUFSIZE){
        next += n;
        return (void *)(next - n);
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

void afree(void *c){
    next = (char *)c;
}

int main(){
    int *num = alloc(sizeof(int));
    *num = 346455;
    printf("%d: %d\n", *num, (int)sizeof(int));
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", *(next - 4), *(next - 3), *(next - 2), *(next - 1));
    afree(num);
}
```

Now, the last printf produces "87, 73, 5, 0".
If you convert all the values into a big binary value you get this: 00000000 00000101 01001001 01010111. If you take that binary value and convert it to decimal you get the original value of *num, which is 346455. So, basically it separates the integer into 4 bytes and puts them into different elements of the array. I think this is implementation-defined and has to do with little endian and big endian. Is this correct? My first prediction was that it would truncate the integer and basically set the value to (integer value) % sizeof(char).

Answer (score -1):

```
int *num = alloc(sizeof(int));
```

Says - 'here is a pointer (alloc) that points to some space, lets says it points to an integer (int*).'

The you say

```
 *num = 5643;
```

Which says - set that integer to 5643.

Why wouldnt it work - given that alloc did in fact return a pointer to a block of good memory that can hold an integer

Comment: Technically it "wouldn't work" because it violates strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.

Comment: @cmaster No. You *may* access an object of any type through an lvalue expression of character type, but the reverse is **not** the case.

Comment: @EOF - I guess I dont understand what that means. The OP's alloc returns void *, just like malloc does. Whats the issue? Are we saying that functions returning void * are UB? Or just if you write to those pointers. How can any malloc work in that case?

Comment: @pm100: `malloc()` is special in that it returns a pointer to an object of no declared type. An array of `char` *does* have a declared type. See C11 draft standard n1570, *6.5 Expressions*, paragraph 6 (effective type) and 7 (permitted accesses by type).

Comment: @EOF You are right. I've looked it up in the standard now: Whether a pointer may be used to modify an object indeed depends on the declared type of that object, even if that type is never used to manipulate the object. So, yes, using a statical array of `char` to back memory allocations indeed results in UB. Interestingly, it would have been ok if the `char` array were dynamically allocated itself (via `malloc()` or `mmap()`), because then the object does not have a declared type. To me the standard wording sounds wrong since the declared purpose is to allow reordering of memory *accesses*...

Comment: @EOF, his alloc function returns a void * also

Comment: @pm100 Whether the function returns `void *` is *entirely* irrelevant. The `char []` **has a type**. Casting a pointer to it to `void*` **does not change the declared type** (This is *incredibly obvious*, otherwise there would not *be* any strict aliasing).

Comment: @cmaster It *does* allow some compiler optimizations: If you have a function that takes two pointers to different types, you can reorder the accesses *unless* one of them is never read after the other is written to.

Comment: @EOF, malloc is declared void * , his alloc is declared void *. Now maybe you are saying that the inside of alloc is illegal, but thats not what you said. You said "malloc is special because it returns a pointer of no declared type (ie void *)"

Comment: @pm100: No, I did **not** say "malloc is special because it returns a pointer of no declared type (ie void *)", because a `void*` has nothing to do with an object of no declared type. Don't put words in my mouth.

Comment: @EOF _: so what does the phrase 'malloc is special because it returns a pointer to an object of no declared type' mean

Comment: @EOF Precisely. And that optimization should be entirely independent of the declared type of either object pointed to by any of those two pointers. How the declared type entered the relevant wording of the standard remains a mystery to me: After all, what we want the compilers to do is reordering those memory accesses, and all the info that the compiler has compiling that function are the types of the pointers, not the declared types of the memory objects behind them. As such, basing the strict aliasing rules on the declared type sounds unnecessarily restricting..At least that's my view of it.

Comment: @pm100: If you *declare an object* like `T foo;`, the object has a declared type. If you take a pointer to it `T *bar = &foo;`, it's a pointer to an object with a declared type. If you cast the pointer `void *baz = bar;`, *it still points to an object of a declared type*. `[m/c/re]alloc()` are special in that the pointer they return points to an object of *no* declared type. You can write *any* kind of object into the memory, provided the allocation was big enough. *That* is what makes `malloc()` special.

Comment: @cmaster Consider what happens when  you pass two pointers to *the same type* to a function. You *can't* make some important optimizations. This is precisely the reason for `restrict`, allowing the programmer to specify "these two pointers point to distinct objects". It's the difference between `memcpy()` and `memmove()`. Now, `restrict` is pretty new to the language (C99 AFAIR). Even before that, it was obvious that accessing an object through an lvalue of a type other than the effective type of the object was not a good idea, and you get *some* of the benefit of `restrict` by forbidding it.

Comment: @EOF: The C99 notion of "effective type" is a nonsensical broken abstraction with unworkable corner cases that cannot be handled reliably without foregoing what should otherwise be useful optimizations.  What's important for optimization is requiring that if two different types are used to access the same storage within some context (which may be drawn narrowly or broadly), one must be visibly derived from another *within that same context*.  There was never any reason for a quality compiler not to recognize that `*(uint32_t*)floatPtr` might access an object of type `float`.